# Is there a better way to bring names into class scope other than to typedef them?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I keep running into this issue:

```
class CCreateShortcutTask : public CTask
{
public:
    CCreateShortcutTask(
        CFilename                         filename,     // shortcut to create (or overwrite)
        Toolbox::Windows::CShellLinkInfo  definition        // shortcut definition
    ) 
    ...
```

Having to spell out Toolbox::Windows::CShellLinkInfo seems highly questionable to me.  This is in a header, so I surely don't wish to issue a **using namespace** declaration or I'll drag that namespace into every client file that includes this header.

But I don't seriously want to have to fully name these things in the class interface itself.  I'd really love to be able to do something like:

```
class CCreateShortcutTask : public CTask
{
    using namespace Toolbox::Windows;
    -or possibly-
    using Toolbox::Windows::CShellLinkInfo;

public:
    CCreateShortcutTask(
        CFilename       filename,       // shortcut to create (or overwrite)
        CShellLinkInfo  definition      // shortcut definition
    ) 
    ...
```

But these seem to be illegal constructs.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

EDIT: [I have asked a broader version of this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902651/c-namespace-headaches)

Comment: Why isn't a private `typedef` suitable?

Comment: I would type the long name, it is provides more context for the people that come after you.

Comment: As to using a private typedef - meh.  It works, but what about all of the symbols that come with the thing I want to work with - helper functions in the same namespace?  Other related classes?  I really have to typedef every symbol in order to use it as "naturally" as if this wasn't a header file, and I could use a using declaration for the scope of the file?

Comment: @Mordachai: any helper functions in the same namespace that take arguments of the typedefed type will be immediately accessible via their unqualified names due to ADL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is a confusion on typedefs.

Using private typedefs is perfectly suitable (and often used). This relies on the fact that in C++ a typedef does not introduce a new type, but a synonym!

```
namespace VeryLongNamespaceYoullNeverWantToSeeAgain
{
  class SuchAStupidNameShouldBeBanned
  {
  public:
    typedef xxx iterator;
    typedef zzz value_type;

    static std::string Print(value_type);
  private:
  };

  void destroy(SuchAStupidNameShouldBeBanned&);
}

namespace short
{
  class MyStruct
  {
    typedef VeryLongNamespaceYoullNeverWantToSeeAgain::SuchAStupidNameShouldBeBanned Stupid;
  public:
    void destroyStupid()
    {
      Stupid::iterator it = m_stupid.begin(), end = m_stupid.end();

      std::cout << "Getting rid of ";
      for (; it != end; ++it) std::cout << Stupid::Print(*it) << " ";
      std::cout << std::endl;

      destroy(m_stupid);
    }

  private:
    Stupid m_stupid;
  };
}
```

Thus, private typedefs don't bother:

- name lookup: `destroy` is correctly invoked
- use of inner typedefs: `iterator` is found
- use of static methods: `Print` is found

So you can really use them without many fuss. Furthermore they don't pollute the global space since they are inner to the class and though visible cannot be manipulated by the client directly so he does not rely on them.

Within the source file, you can use namespace aliasing and using directives (not using namespaces please) more liberally, so it's less of an issue.

Comment: Thanks - this helps clarify some things, and is extremely clearly written. :)

Comment: Although private typedefs are as good as it gets - I would prefer to see the ability to use scoped using declarations (or class scoped using namespace decls).  Here's hoping that this will be better handled in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe namespace alias will help you in some way. You could write the following:

```
namespace TW = Toolbox::Windows; // define short name

class CCreateShortcutTask : public CTask
{
public:
    CCreateShortcutTask(
        CFilename           filename,
        TW::CShellLinkInfo  definition
    )
```

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of such a thing.  I guess that introduces another global name into any clients who #include my header, which isn't ideal. :(

Comment: Yes it does, if you look into the depths of Boost though you'll find they have used it: `namespace mpl_ = boost::mpl;`. Because of the trailing underscore, it's less likely to be used.